# I want add two fields in a single field Using Triggers

Tags: salesforce

I have Two Fields(FirstName,LastName) Using triggers I want add

```
    both in one field Middle Name=(FirstName+LastName).
```

Thanks
kumar

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger ObjBeforeInsert on Obj__c (before insert) {

    for(Obj__c obj:Trigger.new){
        obj.Name= obj.FirstName +''+obj.LastName;
    }
}
```